# Looping through an array (`Object.keys(obj)`) to find a value

Tags: javascript, object

I'm learning Javascript, so pardon any mistakes in how I phrase the question.

I am writing a chess program to practice and learn. Currently, I am trying to write a function to find the color of a piece with the position as the parameter. The relevant pieces of code are as follows. The first two work as they were designed to, but the last does not.

```
let allPieces = board.getElementsByClassName('piece');
```

This sets `allPieces` as an object with the key values the html elemnts representing each piece, both black and white.

```
const getPiecePosition = function(element) {
  let position = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('grid-row-start');
  let letterIndex = alphabet.findIndex(function(letter) {
    return letter === position[0];
  });
  letterIndex += 1;
  return [letterIndex, Number(position[1])];
}
```

This takes a parameter in the form of the `allPieces` object with a specific key and returns the position as an array with the column number first and the row number second. ex. `[2,3]`.

```
const getPieceByPosition = function(position) {
  let pce = Object.keys(allPieces).forEach(function(piece) {
    if (getPiecePosition(allPieces[piece]) == position) {
      return allPieces[piece].borderColor;
    }
  })
  return pce;
}
```

This is the function I am having trouble with. The idea behind it is that it will take each key in the `allPieces` object and loop through them using `forEach()` into the `getPiecePosition()` function to compare it with the position entered as the parameter. Since only one piece can inhabit any tile at once, it should never return multiple values.

I honestly don't know where to start debugging this code, but I have been trying for about an hour. It always just returns `undefined` instead of a truthy value of any kind.

Comment: do you pass an array into your last function for positon like so `getPieceByPostion([2, 3])`?

Answer (score 1):

Your last function has a few issues:

1. ```
   getPiecePosition(allPieces[piece]) == position
   ```

   Assuming `position` is an array, you're trying to compare an array with an array here using `==`. However, since the two arrays are different references in memory, this will always give `false`, even if they contain the same elements:

   ```js
   console.log([2, 3] == [2, 3]); // false
   ```
2. You're trying to `return` from the callback of `.forEach()`. This won't achieve what you want, as `return` will jump out of the `.forEach` callback function, not your outer  `getPieceByPosition()` function. This leads me to your final issue:
3. The `.forEach()` method doesn't return anything. That is, it doesn't evaluate to a value once it is called. This means that `let pce` will always be `undefined` since you're trying to set it to the return value of `.forEach()`. This, in contrast to `let letterIndex`, is different, as `letterIndex` is set to the return value of `.findIndex()`, which *does* have a return value and is determined by the function you pass it.

One additional thing you can fix up is the use of `Object.keys(allPieces)`. While this works, it's not the best approach for looping over your elements. Ideally, you would be able to do `allPieces.forEach()` to loop over all your elements. However, since allPieces is a HTMLCollection, you won't be able to do that. Instead, you can use a regular for loop or a [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to loop over the values in your HTMLCollection.

Alternatively, there is a way to make `allPieces.forEach()` work. 
Instead of using `board.getElementsByClassName('piece');`, you can use the method `.querySelectorAll('.piece')`, which will give you a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Unlike a HTMLCollection, a NodeList allows you to use `.forEach()` on it to loop through its elements.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `getElementsByClassName` [HTMLCollection](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_htmlcollection.asp) Object. You should't use `Object.keys` to loop through each of 'piece' element. Insted, use the follow.

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < allPieces.length ; i++){
    var piece = allPieces[i];
    ... // and, do whatever with the getPiecePosition(piece)
}
```

Comment: using `for(var piece of allPieces) {...}` is nice too!